# Injection of type parameter in a generic class with HK2

Tags: java, jersey, hk2

I'm currently playing with HK2 2.5.0-b05 (which is the version used by Jersey 2.24) and I'm unable to perform a specific type of injection. I was able to generalize my issue and I came up with a simple, small test case.

The code is the following:

```
package com.github.fabriziocucci.test;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.TypeLiteral;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;

public class Test {

    private static class A<T> {

        private final T t;

        @Inject
        public A(T t) {
            this.t = t;
            System.out.println(t);
        }

    }

    private static class B {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServiceLocator serviceLocator = ServiceLocatorFactory.getInstance().create(null);
        ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(serviceLocator, new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(B.class).to(B.class);
                bindAsContract(new TypeLiteral<A<B>>() {}); // <--- ???
            }
        });

        serviceLocator.getService(new TypeLiteral<A<B>>() {}.getType());
    }

}
```

This code leads to the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" MultiException stack 1 of 3
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid injectee with required type of T passed to getInjecteeDescriptor
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetInjecteeDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:546)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getInjecteeDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:585)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:70)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:228)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:70)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2020)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:766)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:713)
    at com.github.fabriziocucci.test.Test.main(Test.java:39)
MultiException stack 2 of 3
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.github.fabriziocucci.test.Test$A errors were found
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:246)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:70)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2020)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:766)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:713)
    at com.github.fabriziocucci.test.Test.main(Test.java:39)
MultiException stack 3 of 3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.github.fabriziocucci.test.Test$A
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:386)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:70)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2020)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:766)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:713)
    at com.github.fabriziocucci.test.Test.main(Test.java:39)
```

I'm sure there is something wrong with my code but I can't figure out what is it.

### UPDATE 1

I just tried the same test with hk2-2.5.0-b28 and, unless my code contains some subtle mistake, the result is the same.

More updates are likely to follow [here](https://github.com/hk2-project/hk2/issues/41).

Comment: This does not work right now as we don't have support for objects that are setting their own ParameterizedType.  However I have added your test to the system and am looking into how we might be able to support this in the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This new feature for hk2 is now available with version hk2-2.5.0-b29.

You can use bindAsContract as in your example but you can also directly set the Type on an ActiveDescriptor or use the new "asType" in the EDSL like:

```
Type type = new TypeLiteral<A<B>>() {}.getType();

ActiveDescriptor<?> ad = BuilderHelper.activeLink(A.class).
            to(type).
            asType(type).build();
```

Comment: Lovely! I just tried it and indeed it works. I hope Jersey is going to pick up this change soon.

Comment: Jersey just picked up hk2 version 2.5.0-b30 so when Jersey next ships a new version that will be integrated with the hk2 which has this feature

Comment: Great news! Should I close the issue on GitHub mentioning the version that fixes it?